# mongokit remove all items from collection

Tags: mongokit

I would like to remove all items from a test collection. My setup is

```
connection = Connection(app.config['MONGODB_HOST'], app.config['MONGODB_PORT'])
db = connection.test_database.tutorial
```

I have a document model class Test which maps to the tests collection. I've tried deleting the collection with both

```
connection.test_database.drop_collection('tutorial.tests')
db.tests.remove()
```

However querying something like

```
list(db.Test.find())
```

still gives me the old data. Something like

```
list(db.tests.find())
```

returns an empty list. However if I add new entries into tests the previous query also doesn't reflect the changes, so I don't think thats accurate either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with this line:
    db = connection.test_database.tutorial
Since it was saying test database and the tutorial collection

removing worked when I changed it to
    db = connection.tutorial